# CDI - is the caller notified when an observer observes an event?

Tags: java, observer-pattern, cdi

I am using CDI and want to know how the caller is notified that the observer has observed an event or didn't.  If no observes act on that event, then I want to do something.  I don't see this being documented anywhere in the documentation other than there was a hint that the caller is notified.

Thanks,

Walter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the caller is notified (it's not what the observer pattern is about actually). But you can try to work this around by:

- you can have a field one the event object - `private boolean consumed` and set it to `true` if it is consumed. Then, (the events are handled synchronously) in the event-producer check that variable.
- firing a new event from the observers that is observed by the event producer
- If you want to drop the benefit of the loose coupling, and you know exactly which the event producer is is, you can `@Inject` it into all listeners, and let them invoke a method on it

Comment: "it's not what the observer pattern is about actually" +1 just for this

Comment: True, I'm thinking how to what it is I want to do.